# Why does if [ !$(grep -q) ] not work when if grep -q does?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, grep

I'm having trouble getting grep to work properly in an if statement. In the following code segment, the if-check always comes up true (i.e. the word is not found), and the program prints NOT FOUND, even though the words are already in ~/.memory.

```
for (( i=0; i<${#aspellwords[*]}; i++)); do
if [ !$(grep -q "${aspellwords[$i]}" ~/.memory) ]; then
   words[$i]="${aspellwords[$i]}"
   printf "\nNOT FOUND\n"
fi
done
```

However, when I test the *following* code in place of the previous segment:

```
for (( i=0; i<${#aspellwords[*]}; i++)); do
if grep -q "${aspellwords[$i]}" ~/.memory; then echo FOUND IT; fi
done
```

It works perfectly fine and finds the word without any issues.

**So what's wrong with the first segment of code?**

Comment: try a space after the exclamation mark, might help.

Comment: You don't want `[ ... ]` if you want to test the return code. Drop those. `[]` is not part of the `if` syntax. `[` is a shell built-in and binary on your system. It just exits with a return code. `if ...; then` tests the return code of `...`.

Comment: Where does `aspellwords` come from? If it's a file, you want something more like `words=( $(grep -Fvxf aspellwordsfile .memory) )` possibly with some mangling if the files are not one word per line already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A number of things are wrong with that first snippet.

You don't want `[ ... ]` if you want to test the return code. Drop those.

`[]` is not part of the `if` syntax (as you can see from your second snippet).

`[` is a shell built-in and binary on your system. It just exits with a return code. `if ...; then` tests the return code of `...`.

`$()` is command substitution. It replaces itself with the *output* from the command that was run.

So `[ !$(grep ...) ]` is actually evaluating `[ !output_from_grep ]` and `[ word ]` is interpreted as `[ -n word ]` which will be true whenever `word` is non-empty. Given that `!` is never non-empty that will always be true.

Simply, as indicated by @thom in his comment (a bit obliquely), add the `!` negation to your second snippet with a space between it and `grep`.

Comment: Solved the issue entirely, and explained clearly why that is. Thank you!