# Why wont my bashrc script work?

Tags: linux, session, ssh, bash

I am trying to create a small script that runs at login from an SSH session. It will create a session if it doesn't exist, connect to a session if it exists and is detached, or do nothing if the session exists and is already attached.

I have this at the bottom of **~/.bashrc** file:

```
if [ $(screen -ls | grep ".testSession (Detached)") ]
then
screen -r testSession

elif [ $(screen -ls | grep "No Sockets found") ]
then
screen -S testSession

else
echo "There is already a session with the Primary ID attached"
fi
```

When I log in I get:

```
-bash: [: too many arguments
There is already a session with the Primary ID attached
```

So I know that it's at least reading the file, but seems to jump to the else statement. I don't see any extra characters/whitespace, and I believe its all instantiated correctly.

I don't really know Bash so its a miracle I got this far. Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I believe my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26248502/258523) covers your issues.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does if \[ !$(grep -q) \] not work when if grep -q does?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26248338/why-does-if-grep-q-not-work-when-if-grep-q-does)

Comment: For your future convenience, [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) automatically points out the problem (missing quotes) and also suggests using `grep -q` as an additional improvement (as in the accepted answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want cmd-substitution for your tests, try

```
if screen -ls | grep -q ".testSession (Detached)" ; then
    screen -r testSession    
elif screen -ls | grep -q "No Sockets found"; then
    screen -S testSession
else
    echo "There is already a session with the Primary ID attached"
fi
```

Recall that `if` evaluates any following cmd-group for its return value (up to the closing `; then`). The `[` is an alias for the `test` command, but as `grep -q` will return `0` if your string is found and something `>0` for other cases, this is all you need to test your screen connections.

IHTH

Comment: @MarkD.Lynch : Glad it helped. Good luck and keep posting.