# Check for installation of xCode always returns true

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to check for an installation of xCode. This:

```
function xCodeCheck(){
    if xcode-select -p; then
        return 1
    else
        return 0
    fi
}
if xCodeCheck -eq 1; then
    echo "it's here"
else
    echo "it's not here"
fi
```

Always returns true though. regardless of if the program is installed. How can I make false be returned if it is not there?

Comment: Spaces matter that `if` statement it testing whether the assignment of `=true` into the `xCodeCheck` variable is succeeding (run `echo "$xCodeCheck"` after that to see what I mean). Shell functions can't return strings only numerical values. To test a string you need to use `[`/`test`. Run your code through http://www.shellcheck.net/ until it returns without errors.

Comment: @EtanReisner I have corrected a couple errors, but still get `SC2034 xCodeCheck appears unused. Verify it or export it.` on line 8. I don't know what that means.

Comment: That's the assignment issue. `if xCodeCheck==true; then` is a variable assignment in the test. The same as `if res=$(some-command-that-might-fail); then` would be. So shellcheck is telling you that you aren't using the `xCodeCheck` variable anywhere so the assignment stands out as "odd". You just want `if xcode-select -p; then` here. You don't need this wrapping function.

Comment: @EtanReisner double equal is assignment in bash?

Comment: @EtanReisner Can you see my most recent update. Is that any better?

Comment: No, `=` with no spaces is assignment. That's not an assignment anymore but it isn't the test you want either. But like I said this wrapping function is pointless. You already have the test you want *in* the function so wrapping it doesn't help you (unless you have other things to add to the function later I guess).

Comment: That code is a call to `xCodeCheck` with two arguments `-eq` and `1`. When `xCodeCheck` then returns `1` (shell failure) the `else` block will run (the logic works out backwards). `0` is true for command returns in the shell, everything else is false.

Answer (score 1):

A working version of your code is this:

```
function xCodeCheck(){
    if xcode-select -p; then
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    fi
}
if xCodeCheck; then
    echo "it's here"
else
    echo "it's not here"
fi
```

Note that I inverted the `0`/`1` return values because exit/return status of `0` in the shell is `true` and everything else is `false`.

That being said that entire wrapping function is pointless.

You could just as easily write:

```
xCodeCheck() {
    xcode-select -p
}
```

and have `xCodeCheck` return the return value of `xcode-select` directly instead of catching it in the `if` and normalizing it to `0` or `1`.

That being said you could then just use `xcode-select -p` in the first test:

```
if xcode-select -p; then
    echo "it's here"
else
    echo "it's not here"
fi
```

If you wanted to keep the manual return and the manual value check your original code would need to be written as:

```
function xCodeCheck(){
    if xcode-select -p; then
        return 1
    else
        return 0
    fi
}

if xCodeCheck; [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "it's here"
else
    echo "it's not here"
fi
```

Comment: ... or `if ! xCodeCheck; then `, which more or less demonstrates that returning 1 for true is silly (in shell).

Comment: Thanks for these detailed explanations. A couple of followups about the last example: what does the syntax mean where you have the two semicolons?(`if xCodeCheck; [ $? -eq 1 ];`) Why is the second one encased in square braces? (`[ $? -eq 1 ];`)

Comment: The syntax of an `if` statement is `if <command_list>; then`. You can put anything in the `<command_list>`. In that last case the command list is *two* commands. The call to `xCodeCheck` and then a call to the `[`/`test` built-in. I explained this a bit more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26248502/258523) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26725499/258523).